# Is there a formula for calculating the sum over squares?

Tags: summation

I know that there are a lot of formulas about sums. However, I would like to ask, is there any formula that calculate the sum over squares? What I mean is that I want a formula if that exists, which gives answer to the following:

$$1+2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + ... + 100^2 ?$$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Take a look at this wikipedia page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_pyramidal_number

Comment: Thanks a lot @MatthewConroy

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=1^2+2^2+\ldots+n^2$

Comment: Thanks a lot friend! Just upvoted